# How do I find a replacement inductor?

Tags: inductor, components

I would like to replace what I believe is a failed inductor on a monitor board.  I have searched per its marking but find nothing, SQEE13 W1.   How can I identify and find a replacement?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The board has a side marked HOT which receives 115 volts.  The component is on the side marked cold.  The bad looking solder was caused by me when removing the component.

Comment: They are custom. If you can’t guess from similar cct’s SOL or from service manual

Comment: Before you burn untold hours trying to figure it out, consider that just because that transformer smoked does not mean it is the actual thing that failed in your circuit.  There a handful of components around it, any one of which fails could overheat that transformer.   i.e. you could install a perfectly good new transformer and be treated to a nice fireworks show when you turn on the power.

Comment: Dan, I think you are getting the point that there isn't a simplistic answer here. One thing that anyone can do and where it would go a long way in getting help from more knowledgeable sorts, is a complete breakdown of the device. Carefully remove the yellow wrap around the coil as well as the core. It's likely that the core itself is an E and I type. If so, you may be able to find a "break line" and can snap them apart with some violence. Or you could photo where things are at and see if anyone can help with further disassembly. One point is to count the wire loops and the get the wire gauge.

Comment: Dan, But if you can break this beast down and take measurements of everything then others can work out much of the details. We'd need the number of turns, wire diameter, and specific measurements about the shape of the core itself -- those needed measurements somewhat depending on what you see once the wire is removed.

Comment: jonk, The cast metal piece is 13 mm square on the outside, 5.7 mm tall with a 1.6 mm wall.  The cast metal part that protrudes inside the coil is 5.7 mm tall, 2.75 mm thick and about 9.8 mm long.  The wire diameter is 0.55 mm and there are 3 layers of 11 coils.  Pin to pin on the connector is 5 mm.  Although melted on the outside, nothing looked bad on the inside.  I can't seem to enter a picture here so will try to add to the original posting.